# Storage Replica Configuration Failure (error code 0x8009030e)

Tags: hyper-v, storage, windows-server-2016, replication

I`m not able to establish a storage replica between 2 windows servers 2016.

**#The script I used**

$SR = @{
SourceComputerName = 'Server-1'
SourceRGName = 'RG-1'
SourceVolumeName = "A:"
SourceLogVolumeName = "B"
DestinationComputerName = "Server-2"
DestinationRGName = "RG-1"
DestinationVolumeName = "A:"
DestinationLogVolumeName = 'b:'
ReplicationMode = 'Synchronous'
}

New-SRPartnership @SR

**#The error I got**

Unable to create replication group RG-1, detailed reason: WinRM cannot process the request. The following
error with errorcode 0x8009030e occurred while using Kerberos authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may
already have been terminated.

Both servers run in Hyper-V VMs. They are located in different networks. The networks are interconnected with a virtual router (VM/GOS: Windows Server2016 running RAS).

**What did I check so far?**

- There is ping between the servers.
- Both servers are logged in into the same AD domain.
- The domain controller is available and pingable from both servers.
- Correct DNS server is set up on both servers.
- PSRemoting is enabled on the remote device.
- WinRM is running on both servers.
- Server-1 is added in TrustedHosts list of Server-2 and Server-2 is is added in TrustedHosts list of Server-1

Could you please help me to figure out how to fix the issue?

Comment: Tell us which step of the procedure to configure and validate WinRM/Powershell in a workgroup environment fails? There obviously is not a session or even evidence of creating a session or knowledge of what a session is.  Powershell is dependent on WinRM. Need to validate each component. If a basic WinRM id command fails remotely, no need to include 95% of the other information.  
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management
 https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting-on-a-standalone-workgroup-computer/

Comment: "Tell us which step of the procedure to configure and validate WinRM/Powershell in a workgroup environment fails?"

Both servers are not part of a workgroup but a domain.

Comment: "Powershell is dependent on WinRM. Need to validate each component"

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Service WinRM | Format-List
Name                : WinRM
DisplayName         : Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {ServerManagementGateway}
ServicesDependedOn  : {RPCSS, HTTP}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : True
CanStop             : True
ServiceType         : Win32OwnProcess

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Service WinRM | Format-List
Name                : WinRM
DisplayName         : Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {}
ServicesDependedOn  : {RPCSS, HTTP}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : True
CanStop             : True
ServiceType         : Win32ShareProcess

Comment: "If a basic WinRM id command fails remotely, no need to include 95% of the other information."

I`m able to run command remotely on server2 (e.g. Get-Service -ComputerName Server-2)

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.